# How to launch app with qr code?

Tags: android

I'm making an android app for gym exercises and I need to open a specific exercise by scanning exercise-specific QR codes.

The application opens if the QR code is `gymassistant://` but i need to launch a specific exercise.

Here's what code i add to manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="gymassistant"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

What should the QR code contain and what should I write in my Activity / Manifest to be able to open a specific exercise?

Answer (score 2):

According to [a related content on Android Developers Site](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html) and [another related topic on the same site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) you should get data from the bundle in your activity and accordingly.

So, when you register a data like `<data android:scheme="gymassistant"/>` you are allowing other apps to open your app with such a link as gymassistant://
However, it is not restricting your app with the remaining part of the URI. For instance, your activity also starts with such a link as `gymassistant://exercise1` or `gymassistant://exercise2` etc.

What you need to do as I mentioned above is to read data in your activity and act accordingly. For example, below code is the simplest way to handle that. I am sure you will find much better ways :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Get the original QR code data
    String data = intent.getData().toString();
    // Extract the exercise id and use it
    String dataArgs = data.replace("gymassistant://", "");
    switch(dataArgs) {
        case "exercise1":
            //show exercise1 related view
            break;
        case "exercise2":
            //show exercise2 related view
            break;
        //ETC
    }
}
```

I hope I could help you with your problem :)

Comment: Here is the code that i made

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HbdEoJZksQB8zT2Q7csP6W5XUepcWhKe

Comment: You can add this code to the activity that you want to start when the QR code is scanned. In other words, it is the code to put to the activity that you indicated your intent filter in your manifest file.

Comment: i get error when i add this Error:(38, 20) error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class ListExercises i add this to my ListExercises.java file..will be good if you check my code it's up

Comment: Well, according to error you get, you already have an onCreate method defined in your ListExercises class (it also needs to extend an Activity base class such as Activity or AppCompatActivity etc.) and you can only have one method with the same name. So, you should copy the content of this method to your onCreate method instead of copying the whole method.

Comment: Also, I recommend you to read [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) about Activity lifecycle to better understand what is onCreate, what is Activity etc. :)

Comment: Can you check the Code that i send you?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be asking to open an app when QR is scanned, and if app isn't installed, open a web page instead of opening some app in phone to scan QR Code.

You might be interested in a new feature called [deep linking](https://pureoxygenlabs.com/how-to-create-a-qr-codes-that-deep-link-to-your-mobile-app/), which opens registered apps when a QR Image is scanned by phone camera, if you have Apple iOS 11. Otherwise, it'll open up a web browser to either a website or redirect to app store to download app (based on fallback setting included in QR).

For users with earlier operating systems, "open your QR code scanning app to scan." (as usual). For those who don't have a QR scanning app, they'd need to download one (to scan QR Codes), or upgrade to a device that supports a similar function to Deep Linking.

Either approach seems to have the same goal (to open an app, either by scanning QR with data or opened by user to scan data in QR).

Comment: Your link is about iOS app only. Do you have any suggestions for Firebase and android apps?

Comment: [Android 8+](https://blog.beaconstac.com/2019/03/how-to-scan-qr-codes-with-android-phones/) allows QR code scanning from phone camera, no need to install reader

Comment: you are probably right. I cannot test because this is an old thread.